# Internet Explorer Drop down menu behavior different from IE8 to IE9+

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown menus generated by javascript. On IE7 and IE8, the dropdown menus by default does not display nor selects any option -this is the coded and ideal behavior.

In IE9 and above the dropdown menus act differently. The menus visually displays the first option but does not select the value of the first option. This is troublesome for our end users who visually assume that an option has been selected already.

Is there a fix so that the dropdown menus in IE9+ behave the same way as IE7 and IE8? Much thanks!

```
for (int combolineid=0; combolineid < lines.length; combolineid++)
{
    String comboLabel = StringUtilities.escapeHtml(JSAeForm.evaluateString(lines[combolineid].getLabel()));
    String comboVal = comboLabel;
    question[groupid] += "\n<option value=\"" + comboVal + "\"" + " title=\"" + comboLabel + "\"";

    if(comboLabel.compareTo(currentValue) == 0)
    {
        question[groupid] += " " + XHTML_SELECTED;
    }

    question[groupid] += ">" + comboLabel + " test" + "</option>";
}
```

Comment: Please share the JavaScript code you are using.

Comment: Shared code, thanks!